# How do I change the default file permissions in Storable?

Tags: perl, file-permissions, store, storable

Can I somehow change the default file permissions when using  the `store` function from [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different approaches to this.  (Of course there are; it's Perl :-) )

First option:  use [`sysopen()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/functions/sysopen.html) to create the file with the specified permissions, then use `store_fd()` and `fd_retrieve()`.  See also the [Perl open() tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Permissions-agrave-la-mode), particularly the "Permissions a la mode" section.

Second option: use [`umask()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/functions/umask.html) to limit the file permissions.  Don't forget to set it back to its original value if you're working with multiple files.

Third option: use [`chmod()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/functions/chmod.html) to set the file permissions manually on a pre-existing file.

The first option is conceptually better because it allows the user to tighten permissions further by controlling the umask themselves.  (Try `help umask` at a shell prompt.  The umask set there applies to all programs run from the shell.  Again, see [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Permissions-agrave-la-mode).)

Comment: I know some of your approaches. But I am interested, if I can do this with the store-function or by setting some Storable-options.

Comment: @mu is too short, If you need an exact permission then there is probably a security related reason and chmod after the file is created is probably not appropriate as it can open you to a race condition. Although if umask is the issue I don't know how it would make the permissions less secure. But it's a better habit to change your umask, create the file, and reset your umask. This ensures that the action is atomic.